# Вызов сторонней программы и передачи ей аргументов

Tags: c++

Задача: программа "А" должна вызвать другую программу "Б", создав отдельный процесс.

*В какой библиотеке, заголовочном файле содержатся необходимые функции для осуществления вызова сторонней программы?* — первый вопрос.

Ко всему прочему, также программе "А" необходимо передать программе "Б" аргументы (строки), дабы они использовались программе "Б". Каким образом  осуществить, во-первых, собственно, передачу данной информации, во-вторых, *ввод этой строковой информации в программу "Б"?* — второй вопрос.

*Примечание:* исходный код программы "Б" неизвестен, её расширение — .exe.

Comment: Может расскажете нам что вы **уже** попытались сделать, чтобы ответить на свой вопрос?

Comment: Просто подскажу направление. Погуглите `c++ system`, почитайте, а потом  внимательно прочтите `man 3 system`.  (я понимаю, что у автора винда, но лучше начинать с POSIX).

Answer (score 1):

Используйте Win API, конкретно CreateProcces(...). Надеюсь, гуглом пользоваться вы можете. Аргументы командной строки (тут я могу ошибаться) могут быть переданы через второй аргумент данной функции, хотя я в этом сомневаюсь.

Answer (score 1):

К примеру, надо запустить sum.exe, который получает на вход два инта и выводит их сумму.
Чтобы это сделать, можно воспользоваться функцией CreateProcess из windows.h.

```
STARTUPINFOA si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

std::string process_name("D://sum.exe");
int a = 5;
int b = 10;
std::string cmd_params(process_name + " " + std::to_string(a) + " " + std::to_string(b));
BOOL res = CreateProcess(NULL,
                         const_cast<LPSTR>(cmd_params.c_str()),
                         NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
                         NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

Первый параметр отвечает за имя процесса, но его можно не указывать, потому что имя всё равно будет передано аргументом командной строки (второй параметр).

Дополнительно: http://vsokovikov.narod.ru/New_MSDN_API/Process_thread/fn_createprocess.htm